# Test suspended function returning Flow in runTest Scope is not finishing. After time it giving timeout error

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am testing the suspend function that returns the flow. I am able to collect that flow in the runTest scope but this test never ends and gives a timeout error after sometime.

```
suspend fun getData() : Flow<DemoData>{
        //return flow
    }
```

In test here

```
"test getData operation" {
        runTest { 
            repo.getData().collect{
                it shouldNotBe null
            }
        }
```

This test never finish and give error as below

> After waiting for 10s, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: [ScopeCoroutine{Active}@46b3a424]

Answer (score 0):

Use `backgroundScope` with `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` if a test never ends and times out after 10 seconds.

```
backgroundScope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)) {
            repo.getData().collect{
                it shouldNotBe null
            }
        }
```

You can refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test#continuous-collection) for backgroundScope and more tips about flow testing.